# create new site in IIS problem

Tags: iis

What is the mistake? Why do I get this error? 82.100.0.178 is my IP address as given by http://whatismyipaddress.com/

[image: Add Web Site error: "82.100.0.178:80:http is an invalid IP address"]
(click to view full size)

Comment: You're going to have to provide way more information for us to help.

Comment: This is a question for [SF] and has been flagged for transfer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing it wrong:

1. **IP address** -- choose "All Unassigned"
2. **Port:** -- 4321
3. **Host name** -- leave blank

If you create a website using these details then you will be able access it from your computer using `http://localhost:4321/`.

Answer (score 1):

Your hostname is wrong just put the IP address only.

This is usually the URL of your website root if you have when associated with a domain name.  e.g www.stackoverflow.com

if you don't have one then using the **external** IP address is required.  For more information about this look up "Host Headers".  Do not put "http" or any port numbers in the host name. This is handled by the other inputs on this form.

You also need to change the IP address at the top to be the **internal** ip address.  This is the IP of the network card that should be listening for requests.  It's usefull if you have multiple network cards.

If you want to change the port number then do so in the textbox provided. You will need to set up NAT if you are planning on recieving traffic on port 80 at the router but a different port on your webserver.

Answer (score 1):

The IP that you get from service/webpage like whatismyipaddress.com in most cases is the IP or gateway or a router. This IP is not assigned to the web server. Generally you want to bind sites to only IPs assigned to the machine, it is on. You can get a list of IPs on that machine by

```
ipconfig /all
```

in the command prompt. These are also listed in the IP address field in "Edit Site Binding" screen. Many times using "All Unassigned" can be used to bind if you don't need the default site (disable the default site).

If you want your site to be available externally, configure the router to send port 80  traffic to this machine. You may have to configure the firewall also.